# Lie algebra of Derivations as a functor?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, lie-algebras

To an associative algebra $A$ one can associate a Lie algebra $\operatorname{Der} A$ of all [derivations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28abstract_algebra%29) $D:A\to A$.

To any morphism of associative algebras $\alpha:A\to B$, how can one associate a morphism of Lie algebras $\alpha_\ast:\operatorname{Der} A\to \operatorname{Der} B$ or $\alpha^\ast:\operatorname{Der} B\to \operatorname{Der} A$ in a functorial way?

Comment: My guess is that this only works in special situations, for example when $\alpha$ is smooth or something like that.

Comment: $\operatorname{Der}(A,M)$ ($M$-valued derivations) is a functor in $M$. As for $\operatorname{Der}(A,A)$, it's in a sense an algebraic version of tangent bundle...

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You should think of $\text{Der}(A)$ as infinitesimal automorphisms of $A$, or equivalently as vector fields on $\text{Spec } A$, and so it isn't functorial with respect to arbitrary maps in the same way that taking automorphism groups or vector fields of manifolds isn't functorial. (However, like taking automorphism groups or vector fields, it is functorial with respect to isomorphisms.)